# Animation doesn’t work in DAE when collada file is exported

Tags: animation, export, collada, dae

Can anyone tell why am I getting a still image of an animation when I export dae file from blender. Although the animation works fine when I play it in blender.

I know that this question has been asked before but it hasn’t been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: I am using Blender 2.82 at the moment. It works for me for move animation. I mean if I move object and make animation of that movement and export object I can use that animation in other application. At the beginning because I forgot choosing  Include Animation option I could not see animation when import collada file. But I am having the same problem with you iif I make modifier animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the export menu change the Transformation Type from Matrix to TransRotLoc.